# Which functions automatically generate new functions?

Tags: functions

In his video http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?channel=362&video=1643, Wolfram gives the following example: the output from

```
dict = Nearest[WordData[]]
```

is a `NearestFunction` object -- a function that may then be evaluated at an input such as:

```
dict["eleephannt"]
```

> {elephant}

How can one determine which other functions `func` similarly generate a `funcFunction`?

(Not sure if the Title correctly captures the meaning of my question!)

Comment: I think this is probably a bit too broad as it is, because there really isn't anything restricting one from writing these kinds of functions oneself, and they can freely appear in packages &c. Are you only interested in the built-in functions that have this kind of output?

Comment: Some generated functions that come to mind: `NearestFunction`, `BooleanFunction`, `InterpolatingFunction`, `FittedModel`, `CompiledFunction`, `DataDistribution` (yes, it's technically a distritbuion, but try evaluating `dist["Properties"]`), and even more in v10: `APIFunction`, `TemplateObject`, `MeshRegion`, `CloudFunction`, etc.

Comment: In addition, in v10 several list processing functions can be used to create a function object that can be passed around and used later.  E.g. `Select[OddQ]` itself is a function.  Try `Select[OddQ][{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}]`.

Comment: To amplify @OleksandrR.'s point: isn't `Function` a function which creates a function? Then there are also things like `ColorData`, and in fact these kind of functions with string arguments seem to have proliferated lately. Maybe you're only interested in `NumericFunction`s?

Comment: I don't think you can scrape Mathematica's namespace to find functions that return functions, because the weak typing of Mathematica implies that return types are generally unknown and you can't systematically query functions to see what they might return.

Comment: What is the motivation behind the question?  Are you just looking for some examples that work like this or are you looking for a reliable programmatic way to decide whether something is a function?  E.g. define `functionQ` which will return `True` when trying `funcionQ@Nearest[{1,2,3}]`?  I think this really isn't possible in Mathematica (as Sjoerd pointed out).

Comment: @Szabolcs: Except for `Derivative`, I didn't recall other built-in functions that produce functions as output; nor  built-in functions that, if one omits trailing arguments, yield functions as output. Such functionality is powerful, so I want to find out about other examples.

Comment: @Oleksandr R.: Yes, I'm aware that one can define such function-generating functions as a user; in fact, I have certainly done so because it's such a useful thing in some situations. That's why I was looking for more built-in functions of this type.

Comment: @murray I have the impression that Mathematica is moving in the direction of using these more heavilty.  For example, in v10 it is possible to pass functions (operators) to `Dataset`s, which are then used for selecting/filtering elements.  It seems this has motivated the introduction of operator forms for `Select`, `Cases`, etc.  In this context it is very useful to have operators that also have parameters that change theire behaviour.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Yes, such examples as indicated in these comments indicate greater availability of such built-in functions. It's *so* much nicer, e.g., to use such functions in Postfix notation than to construct a corresponding pure functions. E.g., `ints = RandomInteger[{2, 100}, 50]; ints // Select[PrimeQ]` rather than `ints // Select[#, PrimeQ] &`.

Comment: @murray I agree.  More generally, it makes it possible to write a program "linearly", i.e. all of it can be read left-to-right (with postfix) or right-to-left (with prefix).  I just looked at this [code golf problem](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/32541/24980) and it was nice to be able to write this: `First@*MaximalBy[Length] /@ GroupBy[First]@Split@Characters[#] &`  All of this reads from right-to-left, the eye doesn't have to jump back and forth.  We can also make it left-to-right: `// Characters // Split // GroupBy[First] // Map[First@*MaximalBy[Length]]`