# Is there a comprehensive list of functions with operator forms?

Tags: function-construction, operators, functional-style

As of version 10, Mathematica sports operator forms for many functions like `Map`, `SortBy`, `Select` which allow you to curry one or more of the arguments. Like

```
m = Map[myFunction];
```

which creates a new function `m` which automatically maps `myFunction` to any list that's passed to it.

As the question title says, is there a comprehensive list of which functions support this now, or do I just have to recheck every function I'm using from now on, in case this feature was added (and is useful in my current problem)?

**Edit:** I just found [this list](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FunctionCompositionAndOperatorForms.html) buried in the docs, but it's not complete (e.g. `GroupBy` is missing).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From version 10.3 you can use `WolframLanguageData`.

```
WolframLanguageData[EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol", "Curryable"]]
```

As of 11.0, this appears to be the most reliable solution:

[image]

Unfortunately, this method is not perfect either: at least `TuringMachine` is missing from it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm accepting this because it seems like a much more idiomatic solution (and is a lot faster). However, I wanted to note that it's missing `CellularAutomaton` and `SubstitutionSystem`.

Comment: As well as `TuringMachine`, actually. It's interesting that these all belong to the same group of functions.

Comment: Quick 10.4 update: the list now also includes `StringFreeQ`, `StringMatchQ`, `StringPosition`, `StringReplace` and `StringReplacePart`. The above three functions are still missing. Furthermore, thanks to the 10.4 update, I've noticed that we're also missing function which are curryable via different names. 10.4 added `UnequalTo` which returns a curried `Unequal`. Likewise, there's 10.3's `EqualTo` which curries `Equal`. I don't know if any other examples like that exist, but they would definitely be worth mentioning in a comprehensive list of these.

Comment: After some more testing, I'm switching the checkmark back to ybeltukov's answer. Weirdly enough it still seems more reliable. The only ones it doesn't report that are included here are `AssociationThread` and `Entity` and as far as I can tell they have no operator forms in the sense that the others have.

Comment: 11.0 update: checkmark goes back to this one. `AssociationThread` and `Entity` have been removed from the list. It also includes `FoldList` and `AlphabeticOrder` which are missing from ybeltukov's solution. While `CellularAutomaton` and `SubstitutionSystem` have been added to this, neither method currently returns `TuringMachine`, which is slightly odd.

Comment: Oh and the "indirect" operator forms like `EqualTo` and `UnequalTo` were added as well. If there are any omissions beyond `TuringMachine`, the other methods don't report it either.

Answer (score 34):

*Edit:* version 11.0 update. Now it is superset of `` TypeSystem`$OperatorForms ``. It now also includes operator forms that have different names than the functions they're currying, like `EqualTo`.

One can find these functions in the documentation by keywords "operator form"

```
Select[Names@"*", StringMatchQ[ToString@ToExpression[# <> "::usage"], 
    "*operator form*"] &]
```

> ```
> {"AllTrue", "AnyTrue", "Append", "Apply", "AssociationMap", \
> "Between", "Cases", "CellularAutomaton", "ContainsAll", \
> "ContainsAny", "ContainsExactly", "ContainsNone", "ContainsOnly", \
> "Count", "CountDistinctBy", "CountsBy", "DatabinAdd", "Delete", \
> "DeleteCases", "DeleteDuplicatesBy", "EqualTo", "Extract", \
> "FeatureDistance", "FirstCase", "FirstPosition", "Fold", "FreeQ", \
> "GreaterEqualThan", "GreaterThan", "GroupBy", "Insert", "KeyDrop", \
> "KeyExistsQ", "KeyFreeQ", "KeyMap", "KeyMemberQ", "KeySelect", \
> "KeySortBy", "KeyTake", "KeyValueMap", "LessEqualThan", "LessThan", \
> "Lookup", "Map", "MapAt", "MapIndexed", "MatchQ", "MaximalBy", \
> "MemberQ", "Merge", "MinimalBy", "NoneTrue", "Position", "Prepend", \
> "Replace", "ReplaceAll", "ReplacePart", "Scan", "Select", \
> "SelectFirst", "SortBy", "StringCases", "StringContainsQ", \
> "StringDelete", "StringEndsQ", "StringFreeQ", "StringMatchQ", \
> "StringPosition", "StringReplace", "StringReplacePart", \
> "StringStartsQ", "SubstitutionSystem", "TakeLargest", \
> "TakeLargestBy", "TakeSmallest", "TakeSmallestBy", "UnequalTo"}
> ```

Unfortunately, this list is missing at least `AlphabeticOrder`, `FoldList` and `TuringMachine`.

Comment: I believe you meant `Select[StringMatchQ[ToString@ToExpression[# <> "::usage"], 
    "*an operator form of*"] &][Names@"*"]`

Comment: Oddly enough, my V10 documentation centre doesn't seem to be up to date, although I just installed it last week. E.g. the `AssociationMap` documentation doesn't contain the operator form yet. Any clue how I can update this? (Searching for "update documentation" etc just leads to results of updating data in Mathematica programs.)

Comment: @MartinBüttner It was added in recent V10.0.1 update

Comment: @ybeltukov Ah I see. Thanks for the quick answer, btw!

Comment: "V10 documentation centre doesn't seem to be up to date" - what a shock.

Comment: I'm switching the accepted answer back to this one, because it still seems to be the most reliable. However, you can improve this one a bit by reducing the query to `*operator form*`. Otherwise, it misses out on some functions like `EqualTo` which are dedicated operator forms for functions of other names (`Equal` in this case). If you don't have 10.4 around yet, let me know and I can update the function as well as the list if you want.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Please update the post, I do not have v10.4 yet.

Answer (score 23):

There is a global variable that purports to contain a list of operator forms, `` TypeSystem`$OperatorForms ``.  I say "purports", because the list is missing some of the forms found by @ybeltukov's method.  But to its credit, it correctly identifies the operator form of `ReplaceAll` which is mentioned in neither a usage message nor the documentation, and also correctly omits `StringCases` which has no operator form despite the usage message claiming otherwise:

```
Needs["TypeSystem`"]

$typeSystem = SymbolName /@ TypeSystem`$OperatorForms;

$usages =
  Select[
    Names@"*"
  , StringMatchQ[ToString@ToExpression[#<>"::usage"],"*an operator form of*"]&
  ];

$usages ~Complement~ $typeSystem
(* {AssociationMap,CountDistinctBy,DeleteDuplicatesBy,MapAt,Merge,StringCases} *)

$typeSystem ~Complement~ $usages
(* {ReplaceAll} *)
```

There are three other operators which exhaustively partition `` TypeSystem`$OperatorForms `` into the categories "left", "right" and "3-2":

```
TypeSystem`$LeftOperatorForms

(* {Map,KeyMap,Apply,Scan,MapIndexed} *)

TypeSystem`$RightOperatorForms

(* {Prepend,Append,GroupBy,CountsBy,Count,Position,FirstPosition,SortBy,KeySelect,
    Select,SelectFirst,Delete,Extract,Replace,ReplacePart,ReplaceAll,Cases,
    DeleteCases,FirstCase,AnyTrue,AllTrue,NoneTrue,KeyExistsQ,KeySortBy,
    KeyTake,KeyDrop,MaximalBy,MinimalBy,MatchQ,FreeQ,MemberQ} *)

TypeSystem`$ThreeTwoOperatorForms

(* {Insert} *)
```

These categories appear to identify the position(s) of the curried arguments.

The results shown here are from version 10.0.1.

Comment: I think it'll be good to note that one has to load the `TypeSystem` package for this to work.

Comment: @RunnyKine Good idea.  Done.