# Bug in Operator Form of StringCases

Tags: bugs, string-manipulation, documentation

fixed in **10.1** (windows)

---

According to the documentation there's an operator form for `StringCases`

```
?StringCases
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is the normal form

```
 StringCases["abcadcacb", "a" ~~ x_ ~~ "c"]
```

> ```
> {"abc", "adc"}
> ```

Now, the operator form:

```
 StringCases["a" ~~ x_ ~~ "c"]["abcadcacb"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Can anyone reproduce this in **Version 10.0.1**? I'm on **Windows 8.1**.

Comment: ditto on Windows 7 and the RPi

Comment: @bobthechemist. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: Same on OS X with V10.0.1. It seems the operator form really isn't available.

Comment: The documentation should have been set to a later version (in this case, by me). Sorry about that.

Answer (score 9):

Indeed, `StringCases` does not have an operator form in 10.0.1.  The documentation and usage message appear to be in error.

`StringCases` does not appear on the list `` TypeSystem`$OperatorForms `` -- although that is by no means conclusive as discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60869/142).  I would argue that it *should* have an operator form, in symmetry with `Cases`.  In any event, there is a bug here either in the documentation or in the implementation of `StringCases`.

Note that operator forms for functions like `StringCases` and `Cases` pose some problems.  For `StringCases`, there are two arguments that could credibly be curried: the pattern and the occurrence count.  But if the caller specifies two arguments, it is ambiguous whether it means `StringCases[patt, n]` or `StringCases["string", patt]`.  Such are the pitfalls of idiomatic currying when the arguments lists were not designed with currying in mind.

None of this reasoning conclusively argues against the single argument operator form which has reasonably unambiguous meaning.  Further more, WRI have already elected to give `Cases` an operator form even though the currying situation there is even worse, with three arguments that could be curried (pattern/rule, levelspec, occurrence count).

Answer (score 4):

fixed in **10.1** (windows):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

code:

```
StringCases["abcadcacb", "a" ~~ x_ ~~ "c"]
StringCases["a" ~~ x_ ~~ "c"]["abcadcacb"]
```

Comment: Thanks for all your work on checking bug status in 10.1! :-)