# Partial sum of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

The problem I have is really basic but I just can't get my head around it.

Suppose I have a list of ordered pairs

```
A = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h}, ...}.
```

I am looking for a function that will give me the average of partial sums of the second element of each pair, like so:

```
f[1] = b/1 = A[[1, 2]]/1
f[2] = (b+d)/2 = (A[[1, 2]] + A[[2, 2]])/2
f[3] = (b+d+f)/3 = (A[[1, 2]] + A[[2, 2]] + A[[3, 2]])/3
....
f[n] = ?
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `Mean /@ FoldList[Flatten[{##}] &, A[[All, 2]]]`

Comment: `ReplaceList[A[[All, 2]], {x__, y___} :> Mean@{x}]`

Comment: @Dr. belisarius. Sorry, I didn't intend to rip off your first comment in my answer. You should post your second comment as answer though, since it is very readable.

Comment: @Sascha No problem :)

Comment: note the best approach may differ if the list is large and you just want a particular `n` vs if you want to tabulate `f` for all `n`..

Comment: @Dr. belisarius: The solution from your first comment also struggles with numeric input (see my comment on my own answer). Try with `A={{1,1}, {2,2}, {3,3}}` and you get an error message because `Mean` does unfortunately not handle cases like `Mean[1]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
      Accumulate@Last@Transpose[A]/Range@Length@A
```

> {b, (b + d)/2, 1/3 (b + d + f), 1/4 (b + d + f + h)}

Comment: Best answer so far in terms of readability and simplicity. I didn't know about Accumulate, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear[f,g, list];
list= {{a,b}, {c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h}}

f[list_,n_]:=Part[FoldList[Plus,Last@Transpose@list] / Range@Length@list, n]
```

or another version I personally prefer (sadly no [operator forms for `FoldList` and `Part`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60045/is-there-a-comprehensive-list-of-functions-with-v10-operator-forms))

```
g[list_, n_]:=list //Transpose
                   //Last
                   //FoldList[Plus, #]& 
                   //Divide[#,Range@Length@list]& 
                   //Extract[n]
```

I especially like that one can out-comment or partially copy the function definition to find out what the function does step by step

**Edit:** Instead of `//Extract[n]` previously `//Part[#,n]&` was used in the definition of `g`. Without regard for a potential difference in performance I now like `Extract[n]` better.

Comment: I remember someone else proposing and/or supporting this use of post-fix notation.  Did you arrive at this style yourself or did you read a post or paper recommending it?  (I ask because I'd like to re-read that but I cannot find it.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. I saw this form first in @Simon Woods answer to this [question on the use of the new operator forms](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56504/v10s-operator-forms-what-are-they-good-for). The formatting of `g` I choose first since not all postfix-operators fit into a single line. In retrospective this may make it even more readable for people that are familiar with imperative programming style.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think I found the blog post you were referring to in your comment (had not seen it before though). It was postet as a comment to your answer in the same question that I linked in my previous comment. [Here it is](http://mathematica-guide.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/new-mathematica-programming-style-part.html)

Answer (score 5):

```
list = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h}};

Mean[Take[Last /@ list, #]] & /@ Range@Length@list
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Just to give one more solution: One can use the Accumulate function here, which sums up the parts, then take the Mean (simply by dividing). So I think with

```
list = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h}}
```

the command

```
Accumulate @ list[[All, 2]] / Range[Length@list]
```

will do the job.

Answer (score 3):

A solution that does not make use of the length of the list and calculates for the whole list.

```
m = MapAt[Mean, {2 ;;}]@FoldList[Flatten@*List, list[[All, 2]]]
(* {b, (b + d)/2, 1/3 (b + d + f), 1/4 (b + d + f + h)} *)
```

If you need to just calculate for a particular $n$ then

```
n = 2;
Mean[list[[1 ;; n, 2]]]
(* (b + d)/2 *)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

So many roads to Rome...

```
list = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h}};

MapIndexed[Divide[#1, #2] &, Accumulate[(Last /@ list)]] // Flatten

(*{b, (b + d)/2, 1/3 (b + d + f), 1/4 (b + d + f + h)}*)
```