# Error with using SortBy in a Map

Tags: sorting

I have a data set in the following format:

```
SomeData = {{a, 1, 2}, {b, 2, 3}, {c, 3, 4}, {b, 1, 9}, 
{c, 1, 10}, {a, 2, 3}, {a, 3, 8}, {b, 3, 4}, {c, 2, 9}};
```

The first element in the sublist is a category while the second element is an index. The third element is a numeric quantity.

My goal is to create a list of lists where each sublist is a collection based on the category and each sublist is sorted by the index. Here is the expected output:

```
{{{a, 1, 2}, {a, 2, 3}, {a, 3, 8}}, {{b, 1, 9}, {b, 2, 3}, 
{b, 3, 4}}, {{c, 1, 10}, {c, 2, 9}, {c, 3, 4}}}
```

There are two approaches to the problem: `GatherBy` first and then `SortBy` or `SortBy` then `GatherBy`.

If I do the `SortBy` first, I receive the expected results:

```
GatherBy[SortBy[SomeData, {#[[1]], #[[2]]} &], #[[1]] &]
```

However, if I try it the other approach, I receive an error:

```
Map[SortBy[# &, #[[2]] &], GatherBy[SomeData, #[[1]] &]]
```

Error:

```
Part::partw: Part 2 of #1 does not exist. >>
```

**UPDATE:**

As [wxffles](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/427/wxffles) points out, I have a simple syntax error in my `Map` function above. The correct code should be:

```
Map[SortBy[#, #[[2]] &] &, GatherBy[SomeData, #[[1]] &]]
```

**END UPDATE**

If I perform the `GatherBy` alone and inspect the first element:

```
GatherBy[SomeData, #[[1]] &][[1]]
```

We see (yes, it is sorted because my example data was sorted for category `a`):

```
{{a, 1, 2}, {a, 2, 3}, {a, 3, 8}}
```

Using the `SortBy` for just the first element works as well:

```
SortBy[GatherBy[SomeData, #[[1]] &][[1]], #[[2]] &]
```

In short, the problem lies in my using Map and SortBy together. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: You have an ampersand in the wrong place.  You need `SortBy[# , #[[2]] &]&`

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much for catching that. I guess when you stare at a piece of code so long your mind sees what it wants to. That indeed fixed the problem, and now I feel silly for asking since it was a simple syntax error. Thank you again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using *Mathematica 10* or later [operator forms](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56504/121) reduce the complexity of your syntax thereby reducing the chance for mistakes.  Note that [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) is eliminated here:

```
SortBy[Extract[2]] /@ GatherBy[SomeData, First]
```

> ```
> {{{a, 1, 2}, {a, 2, 3}, {a, 3, 8}},
>  {{b, 1, 9}, {b, 2, 3}, {b, 3, 4}},
>  {{c, 1, 10}, {c, 2, 9}, {c, 3, 4}}}
> ```

Since [`Sort`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sort.html) will by default tie-break lists of identical length on an element-wise basis you could also do this:

```
Sort[SomeData] ~SplitBy~ First
```

> ```
> {{{a, 1, 2}, {a, 2, 3}, {a, 3, 8}},
>  {{b, 1, 9}, {b, 2, 3}, {b, 3, 4}},
>  {{c, 1, 10}, {c, 2, 9}, {c, 3, 4}}}
> ```