# Preventing Keys from appearing in Query Output (+ the casting of Ascending/Descending operators)

Tags: programming, query

One of the challenges of coming to grips with `Query`'s on `Association`'s and `Dataset`s is inculcating an internal programming model of how they act and combine. This, in turn, depends critically on whether `Query` operators are *ascending* or *descending* either when acting alone or in concert as part of a function/query composition. Take the following example:

```
data = <|
 "key" -> 1,
 "keyA-Z" -> <|
  "keyA" -> <|
   "key1" -> A1,
   "key2" -> A2,
   "key3" -> A3|>,
  "keyB" -> <|
   "key1" -> B1,
   "key2" -> B2,
   "key3" -> B3|>
            |>
         |>;
```

Suppose we want to extract all elements at the `"key2"` level - here `{A2,B2}`. The query

```
Query["keyA-Z", All, "key2"]@data

    (*   <|"keyA" -> A2, "keyB" -> B2|>   *)
```

does the job except for including the keys and while these can be readily peeled off ( `Query["keyA-Z", All, "key2"]@data//Values`), for "composability purposes" it's nice to be able maintain the operator form of the query by aiming to bring `Values` into the query itself.

---

**Initial Attempts and Ascending/Descending casting:**

At first pass

```
Query["keyA-Z", All /* Values, "key2"]@data
(* 
  <|
    "keyA" -> <|"key1" -> A1, "key2" -> A2, "key3" -> A3|>, 
    "keyB" -> <|"key1" -> B1, "key2" -> B2, "key3" -> B3|>
  |>[[Values]][[All, "key2"]]
*)
```

seems appropriate noting from the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html):

> When one or more descending operators are composed with one or more
>   ascending operators (e.g. `desc /* asc`), the descending part will be
>   applied, then subsequent operators will be applied to deeper levels,
>   and lastly the ascending part will be applied to the result.

e.g.

```
  Query["keyA-Z", All /* f, "key2"]@data
   (* f[<|"keyA" -> A2, "keyB" -> B2|>] *)
```

but as observed in its output the catch here is that `Values` is a *descending* operator (unlike the generic, *ascending* `f`). We can try turning it into an ascending one by wrapping it in a `Query` (subqueries tend to be ascending)

```
Query["keyA-Z", All /* Query[Values], "key2"]@data
(* <|"keyA" -> A2, "keyB" -> B2|>[[Values]] *)
```

but no beer. One way however, of turning `Values` into a generic, ascending function is by reverting to its pure form

```
Query["keyA-Z", All /* (Values@# &), "key2"]@data
 (* {A2, B2} *)
```

While this works and provides an idiom for casting descending operators into ascending ones, (and also bringing post-processing within queries), it's also rather inelegant. In fact things seem to have come full circle; in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56504/v10s-operator-forms-what-are-they-good-for) the value of eschewing pure functions in favour of operator forms was compellingly made in several answers but here their re-introduction seems necessary as part of an operator's specification?

So can this "keyless `All`" `Query` be constructed in non-pure terms? - more broadly, is there a way of systematically specifying `Query` operators as either ascending or descending?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I do not believe that this addresses all points in your question I note that the specific query you attempted works in this form:

```
Query["keyA-Z", Values /* All, "key2"] @ data
```

> ```
> {A2, B2}
> ```

The same with `Dataset`:

```
Dataset[data]["keyA-Z", Values /* All, "key2"]
```

[image]

Based on this I would have thought that [`Composition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html) also would work but it does not:

```
Query["keyA-Z", All @* Values, "key2"] @ data
```

> Values::invrl: The argument Values[Slice[key2]] is not a valid Association or a list of rules. >>

Comment: Actually `Query["keyA-Z", Values, "key2"]@data` also gives `{A2, B2}
`  suggesting `All` wasn't needed after all?

Comment: @Ronald I hadn't thought of that but I think it makes sense.  That answers your actual question (as I understand it) even less however?

Comment: Yes it means that the example motivates somewhat less the, still relevant and broader casting question. It does mean though that my intuition about using `All` for listing "leaves" in nested `Association`'s needed updating. The right construct here is `Values` - suppose we wanted all the leaves `{A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3}` then not `All` at all but instead `Query["keyA-Z", Values /* Flatten, Values]@data`

Comment: forgot to accept, but as part of doing so now, for quick reference for others, perhaps you could include the "obvious" solution given in the first comment as the first line in your answer?

Comment: @RonaldMonson, "suggesting All wasn't needed after all?" - that's right, `All` hardly if ever needed in query composition.

Comment: @RonaldMonson The 4 forms `All/*Values`, `Values`, `Values/*All` or `All@*Values`  work the same in v 11.1.1.0. (don't know for previous versions). Only the 2 first ones make sense for me.