# Split according to list and apply rule

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list which looks some thing like this

```
{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10}
```

Now I want to split it according to lengths `{1,2,3,4}` so that I would have

```
{{a1},{ a2, a3}, {a4, a5, a6},{ a7, a8, a9, a10}}
```

and I want to apply the rule with itself. For example: after rule application, the answer should become

```
{{a1},{a2->a3},{a4->a5->a6},{a7->a8->a9->a10}}.
```

I have tried to use `Split` and `Partition` function but not getting the desired result.
Is there any other function that accomplishes this? If not how can I do this?

Comment: The first part of your question I answered here: [(7511)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7511/121)

Answer (score 14):

Depending on the precedence you want for `Rule`, you can use either

```
Fold[Rule, #] & /@ 
 Internal`PartitionRagged[{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10}, {1, 2, 3, 4}]

(* {a1, a2 -> a3, (a4 -> a5) -> a6, ((a7 -> a8) -> a9) -> a10} *)
```

or

```
Fold[Rule[#2, #1] &, #] & /@ Reverse /@ 
 Internal`PartitionRagged[{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10}, {1, 2, 3, 4}]

(* {a1, a2 -> a3, a4 -> a5 -> a6, a7 -> a8 -> a9 -> a10} *)
```

To end up with the requested output, you can evalute `List /@` on the resulting expressions.

**Update**

To avoid mapping twice in the last solution, one could use `Fold[Rule[#2, #1] &, Reverse@#] &` instead of `Fold[Rule[#2, #1] &, #] & /@ Reverse`.

Also, instead of using `List /@` on the output as suggested above, one could directly enclose the `Fold` function between braces, e.g.

```
{Fold[Rule[#2, #1] &, Reverse@#]} & /@ 
  Internal`PartitionRagged[{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10}, {1, 2, 3, 4}]

(* {{a1}, {a2 -> a3}, {a4 -> a5 -> a6}, {a7 -> a8 -> a9 -> a10}} *)
```

Comment: With `// Partition[#, 1] &` in the end to yield the exact requested output.

Comment: @anderstood. Or `{#} &/@ result`.

Comment: @march `List /@ result` is  probably clearer for a beginner

Comment: @belisariushassettled. And for an established user/expert, too.

Answer (score 8):

The partitioning aspect of your question is already addressed in detail in [Partitioning with varying partition size](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7511/121).

The second aspect of your question amounts to performing a [right fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29#Folds_on_lists).  For the case at hand this might be done most easily using pattern matching:

```
rule[a___, x_, y_] := rule[a, x -> y]
rule[x_] := x
```

This is essentially a multi-argument `Rule` with a defined precedence.  It does this:

```
rule[a1, a2, a3, a4]
```

> ```
> a1 -> a2 -> a3 -> a4
> ```

You can then [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) this function to a list, or list of lists.  Using my `partitionBy` function from the referenced Q&A your operation is then:

```
in = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10};

List /@ rule @@@ partitionBy[in, # &]
```

> ```
> {{a1}, {a2 -> a3}, {a4 -> a5 -> a6}, {a7 -> a8 -> a9 -> a10}}
> ```

Xavier also provided a right fold method, and one that can be much more efficient in certain cases due to the optimizations within [`Fold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html).  Let's make it an abstraction, and add an [Operator Form](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56504/121) while we're at:

```
Default[foldr] = Sequence[];
foldr[f_][p__] := foldr[f, p]
foldr[f_, x_., a : _[__]] := Fold[#2 ~f~ #1 &, x, Reverse @ a]
```

It does this:

```
foldr[oo][{a1, a2, a3, a4}]
```

> ```
> oo[a1, oo[a2, oo[a3, a4]]]
> ```

Your operation is then:

```
in = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10};

List /@ foldr[Rule] /@ partitionBy[in, # &]
```

> ```
> {{a1}, {a2 -> a3}, {a4 -> a5 -> a6}, {a7 -> a8 -> a9 -> a10}}
> ```

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to use the handy but undocumented `PartitionRagged`, you could go by:

```
l  = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10}; 
r = Range[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 8 Length@l])]
ls = Transpose@{# - PadLeft[Most@r, Length@r], #} &@Accumulate@r;
l[[#1 ;; #2]] & @@@ ls

(*{{a1}, {a2, a3}, {a4, a5, a6}, {a7, a8, a9, a10}}*)
```

Comment: "List /@ result is probably clearer for a beginner" – belisarius has settled 16 mins ago :)

Comment: @Kuba What am I missing?:(

Comment: A solution clear for beginner :)

Comment: @Kuba Ahhh ... that's Xavier's ! :D

Comment: A documented alternative to `PartitionRagged` could be: `FoldPairList[TakeDrop, {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10}, {1, 
  2, 3, 4}]`.

Comment: @Kuba Is this any better?:) `l[[#1 ;; #2]] & @@@ 
 Partition[(Flatten@
     FoldList[#1 + #2 &, {0, 1}, 
      Range@Ceiling@Sqrt@Length@l])[[2 ;; -2]], 2]`

Comment: @Xavier Oh, on v9 still here

Answer (score 3):

Just for something different:

```
pf[lst_, pt_] := Module[{p = Join @@ (Table[#, {#}] & /@ pt)},
  Last@Reap[Inner[Sow, lst, p, List], _, #2 &]]
```

So,

```
m = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10};
pf[m, {1, 2, 3, 4}]
```

yields:

```
(*{{a1}, {a2, a3}, {a4, a5, a6}, {a7, a8, a9, a10}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10};
ord = {1, 2, 3, 4}

Prepend[
  Map[Take[lst, #] &,
    Map[{#[[1]] + 1, #[[2]]} &, Partition[Accumulate[ord], 2, 1]]
   ],
  {lst[[1]]}
 ] //. {a___, {b_, c_, p___}, d___} :> {a, {b -> c, p}, d}

{{a1}, {a2 -> a3}, {(a4 -> a5) -> a6}, {((a7 -> a8) -> a9) -> a10}}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10};

{ToExpression @ StringRiffle[#, "->"]} & /@ TakeList[list, {1, 2, 3, 4}]
```

{{a1}, {a2 -> a3}, {a4 -> a5 -> a6}, {a7 -> a8 -> a9 -> a10}}

`TakeList` since  V 11.2 and `StringRiffle` since V 10.1

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
list = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10};
t = TakeList[list, {1, 2, 3, 4}];
TextString[#, ListFormat -> {"{ ", "->", " }"}] & /@ t // ToExpression
```

> {{a1}, {a2 -> a3}, {a4 -> a5 -> a6}, {a7 -> a8 -> a9 -> a10}}

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

**(1)**

```
List@*ResourceFunction["FoldRight"][Rule] /@ 
  TakeList[{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10}, {1, 2, 3, 4}]

(* {{a1}, {a2 -> a3}, {a4 -> a5 -> a6}, {a7 -> a8 -> a9 -> a10}} *)
```

**(2)**

```
List@Fold[ReverseApplied[Rule], #1, ##2] & /@ 
  Reverse[TakeList[{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10}, {1, 2, 3, 4}], 2]

(* {{a1}, {a2 -> a3}, {a4 -> a5 -> a6}, {a7 -> a8 -> a9 -> a10}} *)
```

**[Right Fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29#Folds_on_lists)**

```
ResourceFunction["FoldRight"][f]@{a, b, c, d}

(* f[a, f[b, f[c, d]]] *)
```

```
Fold[ReverseApplied[f], #1, ##2] &@Reverse[{a, b, c, d}]

(* f[a, f[b, f[c, d]]] *)
```