# Confusing alternative definition of a function

Tags: function-construction, core-language

I saw a function defined something like the following:

```
f[n_Integer][r, θ] = Sin[n r π/L] Cos[n r L π θ/4]
```

My question is, why did my professor define the function like above, instead of using `f[n_Integer, r_, θ_]`? What is the difference? I could not find any answers on Mathematica, or google, or here.

If this has been asked before,and I did not find it, I apologize.

Comment: Related concepts: [Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), `Subvalues`. But just for calculation purposes, no big difference.

Comment: So now you can use f[1]@@@something, while if you use the latter definition, you can only use f[1,#1,#2]&@@@something

Comment: @Wjx, or `f[1, ##] & @@@ something`, if wanted. But, `f[1] @@ something` can be cleaner in some cases.

Comment: It's like $f_n(r,\theta)$ instead of $f(n,r,\theta)$ in mathematics.  She or he is thinking of $n$ in a qualitatively different way (as parametrizing a sequence of functions, most likely).

Comment: @J.M. yep~that'll be better :)

Comment: did he use underscores on r,theta? As is its hard to see the point

Comment: The form you give is an alternative to `f[n_Integer, r, θ]` not `f[n_Integer, r_, θ_]`

Comment: Proposed duplicate: [(7999)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7999/121).  Recommended reading:  [(544)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/544/121), [(5686494)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5686494/121), [(56504)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56504/121)

Comment: Thanks all. And yes he used the underscores like I had in the original

Comment: Also , I thought always when defining functions, we used underscores? What does this do differently when not using them in the example above?

Comment: @user57404. It forces you to always write exactly` [r, θ]` to get the evaluator to use the this particular definition. As Michael E2 noted, object seems to be to implement indexing on `f`.