# Difference in how arguments are passed to functions

Tags: function-construction

Given a custom function `f`, what is the difference between passing arguments like

```
f[x_][y_][w_]
```

and

```
f[x_,y_,w_]
```

or other such variations among these? It is often that I see functions using both/some notations, but I can't quite understand the underlying difference.

Comment: See [Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) and the [currying tag on this site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/currying?tab=Votes) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5686494) from the times before this site existed :-)

Comment: @MarcoB Much appreciated!

Comment: In the second case you supply the arguments all at the same time and the function is evaluated right away. In the first case you supply x, then sometime later y and only after you supply the final w the function is evaluated. This is the most common use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to [@Marco's comment on currying](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/264444/difference-in-how-arguments-are-passed-to-functions#comment658944_264444), see "operator forms", for instance [V10's Operator Forms - what are they good for?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56504/v10s-operator-forms-what-are-they-good-for) and [in the docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FunctionCompositionAndOperatorForms.html).

Note in `f[x][y][w]`, any `Attributes` that `f` has apply only to `f[x]`;  in `f[x, y, w]`, the `Attributes` of `f` apply to `f[x, y, z]`. For instance `HoldAll`. If `f` has the attribute `HoldAll`, then in evaluating `f[x][y][w]`, the argument `x` is passed to `f` unevaluated; but `y` and `w` are evaluated and their values are passed to `f`. In evaluating `f[x, y, w]`, all arguments would be passed unevaluated.

If no attributes, the evaluation sequence is in the two cases shown by `TracePrint`:

```
TracePrint[f[x][y][w]]

 f[x][y][w]   <- Expression to be evaluated
   f[x][y]    <-  The head of f[x][y][w] (to be eval.)
     f[x]     <-   The head of f[x][y] (to be eval.)
       f      <-    The head of f[x] (evaluated)
       x      <-    The arg of f[x] (evaluated)
     y        <-   The arg of f[x][y] (evaluated)
   w          <-  The arg of f[x][y][w] (evaluated)
f[x][y][w]    <- The result of f[x][y][w] (evaluated)

TracePrint[f[x, y, z]]

  f[x,y,z]    <- Expression to be evaluated
    f         <-  The head of f[x,y,w] (evaluated)
    x         <-  The 1st arg of f[x,y,w] (evaluated)
    y         <-  The 2nd arg of f[x,y,w] (evaluated)
    z         <-  The 3rd arg of f[x,y,w] (evaluated)
f[x, y, z]    <- The result of f[x][y][w] (evaluated)
```

Note that in the curried/operator form `f[x]` or `f[x][y]` could evaluate to something else:

```
ClearAll[ff, gg];
ff[a_][b_] := gg[a + b];
TracePrint[ff[x][y][w]]
(*  Out[]= <exercise for the reader>  *)
```